# get is not valid without active transaction - hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate-5.x

I keep getting this error even though i have started the transaction manually.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
transaction = session.getTransaction();
if(!transaction.isActive())
{
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
}

accessToken = session.get(OAuthAccessToken.class, token);
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>

    <!-- Use the C3P0 connection pool. -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

    <!-- Disable second-level cache. -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts">false</property>
    <property name="max_fetch_depth">3</property>

    <!-- Bind the getCurrentSession() method to the thread. -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>
```

`HibernateUtils`

```
public class HibernateUtil
{
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static
{
    try
    {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
        config.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", String.valueOf(ConfigManager.getInstance().getBoolean(Consts.CONFIG_DB_SHOW_SQL, false)));
        config.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", String.valueOf(ConfigManager.getInstance().getBoolean(Consts.CONFIG_DB_FORMAT_SQL, false)));

        config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", ConfigManager.getInstance().getString(Consts.CONFIG_DB_DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"));
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", ConfigManager.getInstance().getString(Consts.CONFIG_DB_DRIVER_CLASS, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"));
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", ConfigManager.getInstance().getString(Consts.CONFIG_DB_URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost/photometo"));
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", ConfigManager.getInstance().getString(Consts.CONFIG_DB_USERNAME, "root"));
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", ConfigManager.getInstance().getString(Consts.CONFIG_DB_PASSWORD, ""));
        config.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", ConfigManager.getInstance().getString(Consts.CONFIG_DB_HBMDDL_AUTO, "update"));
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
{
    return sessionFactory;
}

}
```

I noticed that this starts happening after some time. If i restart tomcat or re-deploy app, problem goes away

Comment: given configuration looks fine. Is this possible to push minimum viable version of  code which can demonstrates the issue on githhub? Or add at least stack trace to question.

Answer (score 2):

You never started a Transaction and you can't get a transaction of other. That's why you are getting an error when you are calling it:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    transaction = session.getTransaction(); // Here is the error! You can't get an active transaction, becasue there isn't even started 
    if(!transaction.isActive()) // transaction.isActive() is usually for closing a transction in the end
    {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction(); // You are starting the transaction!
    }

accessToken = session.get(OAuthAccessToken.class, token);
```

You can't get the active transaction because there isn't even started. Change the code to this:

```
 // Non-managed environment idiom with getCurrentSession()
try {
    factory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

    // do some work
    ...

    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
```

The correct why of starting transactions in a Non-managed environment is this from the [Documentation of Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged):

```
// Non-managed environment idiom with getCurrentSession()
try {
    factory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

    // do some work
    ...

    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}

// Non-managed environment idiom with getCurrentSession() try {
    factory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

    // do some work
    ...

    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit(); } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message }
```

Following the documentation of [getTransaction()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#getTransaction()), your current session doesn't started a transaction.

```
getTransaction()
      Get the Transaction instance associated with this session.
```

And here is why start a transaction [11.2 Database Transaction demarcation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation):

> Database, or system, transaction boundaries are always necessary. No
>   communication with the database can occur outside of a database
>   transaction (this seems to confuse many developers who are used to the
>   auto-commit mode). Always use clear transaction boundaries, even for
>   read-only operations.

And having long transaction is bad for the DB, because generated a lot of locks in your DB,[Session and transaction scopes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics)

> In order to reduce lock contention in the database, a database
>   transaction has to be as short as possible. Long database transactions
>   will prevent your application from scaling to a highly concurrent
>   load. It is not recommended that you hold a database transaction open
>   during user think time until the unit of work is complete.

Comment: I did start the transaction, if you look at my question you will also see this: `transaction = session.beginTransaction();`

Comment: But you are trying to call `transaction = session.getTransaction();` before starting it, that's why the error.

Comment: No, error is thrown on `session.get` not `getTransaction`

Comment: Edited the answer. You can't get the active transaction because there isn't an active one. So that's why the Exepction.

Comment: No, that is wrong, if transaction is already started than `beginTransaction` will throw exception